# DayName giving incorrect days with TimeZoneConvert

Tags: bugs, date-and-time

So I used `TimeZoneConvert` to get the time in GMT:

```
TimeZoneConvert[Now,"GMT"]
```

It outputs a date object that says `Tuesday 14 March 2017 02:45:08 GMT`.

But when I then try:

```
DayName @ TimeZoneConvert[Now, "GMT"]
```

I get `Monday`, even though the date object is a Tuesday. What's going on here?

[image: commands]

Comment: Can somebody with version 10.x add the customary header for bug posts, please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Bug Confirmed by Wolfram Research

**My time zone is GMT+8, which is used in this answer.**

I can only explain how you get the incorrect answer.

First we need to read the definitions to trace the evaluation. The powerful tool I used is `` GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions ``. I will just show the main steps.

First store that converted date object in t, `t = TimeZoneConvert[Now,"GMT"]`.

Check what's inside

```
t//InputForm
DateObject[{2017, 3, 14}, 
 TimeObject[{5, 58, 23.634473}, 
  TimeZone -> "GMT"], 
 TimeZone -> "GMT"]
```

From the definitions of `DayName`,

```
DataPaclets`CalendarDataDump`iDayName[t]
(*Monday*)
```

Then,

```
DataPaclets`CalendarDataDump`doDayName[t]
(*Monday*)
```

Then,

```
DataPaclets`CalendarDataDump`ToInternalDate[{"Gregorian", t}, DayName]
(*{"Gregorian", 2017, 3, 13, 21, 58, 23.6345}*)
```

Here we noticed that this function AGAIN subtracted 8 hours from the date, which is incorrect. Its code mainly contains two parts, the first is roughly

```
System`DateObjectDump`$tempDate = t;
System`DateObjectDump`correctTimeZoneOffset[
 System`DateObjectDump`iObjectTimeZone[t]]
(*I added the first line to make the code works, otherwise it returns $Failed, I got the value of $tempdate from tracing*)
```

This returns `0`, which is the time zone for this date. The return value of this function is

```
DateList[Join[PadRight[date, 3, 1], First @ time], TimeZone -> tz]
```

which is

```
DateList[Join[PadRight[{2017, 3, 14}, 3, 1], 
  First @TimeObject[{5, 58, 23.634473}, TimeZone -> "GMT"]], 
 TimeZone -> 0]
```

in our case. Unfortunately, from the docs of `DateList`

> DateList[TimeZone->z] gives the date and time inferred for time zone z by assuming that your computer is set for the time zone specified by $TimeZone. »

It is assuming the input, `{2017, 3, 14, 5, 58, 23.6345}` is the local time, and converts it to `TimeZone -> 0`, so then another 8 hours is subtracted from it, finally we get

```
{2017, 3, 13, 21, 58, 23.6345}
```

Comment: @numbermaniac of course. I have filled a support form. The case number is 3859858

Comment: Awesome, thanks!